# Local storage in textboxes using Jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, local-storage

I am new in jquery and localstorage. I want to use localstorage to all textboxes using jquery.

```
<input id="in-1" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="in-2" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="in-3" type="text" />
<br />
<input id="in-4" type="text" />
<br />
```

I am trying to follow this script:

```
(function ($) {
if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {
    $.each($("input[type=text]"), function () {
        localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")));
    });
    $("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());

    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

But I couldn't make this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the value back

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {
        //set the value to the text fields
        $("input[type=text]").val(function () {
            return localStorage.getItem(this.id);
        });
        $("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {
            localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hb8eW/)

Comment: One more thing what is the difference between onblur and onchange?

Comment: @user3230425 onblur will be fired every time the focus is lost.. but change will fired only of the value in the input is changed - you need to use change event only

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {

        // will get value of specific id from the browser localStorage and set to the input 
        $("input[type=text]").val(function () {
            return localStorage.getItem(this.id);
        });

        // will set values in browser localStorage for further reference
        $("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {
            localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sf3ZU/1/).

**Details:**

Using local storage in modern browsers is ridiculously easy. All you have to do is modify the `localStorage object` in JavaScript. You can do that directly or (and this is probably cleaner) use the `setItem()` and `getItem()` method:

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla');
```

If you read out the favoriteflavor key, you will get back “vanilla”:

```
var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
// -> "vanilla"
```

To **remove** the item, you can use — can you guess? — the `removeItem()` method:

```
localStorage.removeItem('favoriteflavor');
var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
// -> null
```

That’s it! You can also use **sessionStorage** instead of **localStorage** if you want the data to be maintained only until the browser window closes.

The complete [reference here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/). It should give you more knowledge about `localStorage`.